# Get attribute applied to this property in parent

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

Is it possible to get the value of an attribute applied to a property from inside the property itself?
For example:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [TestAttribute(Value="TestValue")]
    public TestClass TestProperty { get; set; }

    [TestAttribute(Value="AnotherValue")]
    public TestClass AnotherTestProperty { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public string ReturnSomething()
    {
        // Get 'TestValue' or 'AnotherValue'
        // from 'TestAttribute' here depending on
        // which property ReturnSomething() is called on
    }
}
```

**Edit:** To clarify. I am trying to achieve this without passing any reference to the parent, or any strings representing the property name into the `ReturnSomething` method.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DemoApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
            Console.WriteLine("Return-Value: " + testClass.ReturnSomething("TestProperty", typeof(TestModel)));
            Console.WriteLine("Return-Value: " + testClass.ReturnSomething("AnotherTestProperty", typeof(TestModel)));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class TestAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string Value
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class TestModel
    {
        [TestAttribute(Value = "TestValue")]
        public TestClass TestProperty { get; set; }

        [TestAttribute(Value = "AnotherValue")]
        public TestClass AnotherTestProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public string ReturnSomething(string propertyName, Type modelType)
        {
            string returnValue = "";

            foreach (var property in modelType.GetProperties())
            {
                if (property.Name == propertyName)
                {
                    // Find Attributes
                    Attribute[] cAttributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<Attribute>().ToArray();

                    if (cAttributes != null)
                    {
                        // Iterate throught all attributes
                        foreach (System.Attribute cAttribute in cAttributes)
                        {
                            if (cAttribute is TestAttribute)
                            {
                                returnValue = (cAttribute as TestAttribute).Value;
                                break; // Break after first
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can you make sure propertyName will be "TestProperty" ?

Comment: That is only an example, not a full use-ready code. Later hje can make a Parameter of it or something else. But this is the way it works.

Comment: @Selman22 i improved my code. His class-name is TestClass, so i think he only want a schematic answer...

Comment: ofcourse you can make it that way but still it doesn't answer the question. he wants to do it without passing explicit parameter like when you call TestModel.TestProperty.ReturnSomething() it should return TestValue which is not possible as far as I'm aware.

Comment: No, he said: **which property ReturnSomething() is called on**, please read the complete question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to get the attributes of a property within the property itself using .net reflection. To do this however you would have to flesh out the getter code of the property and not use an automatic property.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
    class TestAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    [Test(Value = "Hello")]
    public string MyTestProperty
    {
        get
        {
            var typeInfo = GetType();
            // Get the PropertyInfo descriptor for this property
            var propInfo = typeInfo.GetProperty("MyTestProperty");

            // Get custom attributes applied to the property
            var attr = propInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<TestAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

            // If we have an attribute, then return its Value
            return attr != null ? attr.Value : "No Attribute";
        }
    }
```